# How to traverse back to the parent node in the XML file by using Xpath(using XSLT) query?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

Let us have a xml tree of depth N. I have traveresd the last node means i am at last note. Now i wanted to go back to some level up (say at N-3) in the xml tree from that last node.

Please let me know the syntax for the XPATH query so that i can reached at intended node in the xml tree.

Answer (score 54):

**Use**:

```
ancestor::node()[3]
```

or

```
../../..
```

Comment: +1 for ancestor axe plus position predicate solution that can be parameterized