# Selenium How to Find Xpath based on Text conditions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have been learning selenium and Implementing It.I tried uploading files from the bot. During this  I came to know the position(upload button content)  keeps on changing on each reload. I managed to trace out option for .jpg file but I cannot track .pdf file uploading. Much detail on my code below.

```
<div _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="form-group document-upload" xpath="1">
    <div _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="document-upload-info">
        <span _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="document-type">
            KYC Form <!----><span _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" style="margin-left:5px;color:red;">* </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <!----><!---->
    <label _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="btn btn-outline upload-button" style="border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 0.25rem; border-color: #0078D7; color: #0078D7 !important;">
        Upload <input _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" hidden="" multiple="" type="file" accept=".pdf">
    </label>
    <!----><!----><!---->
</div>


<div _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="form-group document-upload" xpath="1">
    <div _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="document-upload-info">
        <span _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="document-type">
            Photo  Form <!----><span _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" style="margin-left:5px;color:red;">* </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <!----><!---->
    <label _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="btn btn-outline upload-button" style="border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 0.25rem; border-color: #0078D7; color: #0078D7 !important;">
        Upload <input _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" hidden="" multiple="" type="file" accept=".jpg">
    </label>
    <!----><!----><!---->
</div>

<div _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="form-group document-upload" xpath="1">
    <div _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="document-upload-info">
        <span _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="document-type">
            Citizenship   Form <!----><span _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" style="margin-left:5px;color:red;">* </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <!----><!---->
    <label _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="btn btn-outline upload-button" style="border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 0.25rem; border-color: #0078D7; color: #0078D7 !important;">
        Upload <input _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" hidden="" multiple="" type="file" accept=".pdf">
    </label>
    <!----><!----><!---->
</div>
```

I did following way to upload image.

```
photo_filepath_input_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@accept='.jpg']").send_keys(
                    '/home/daniel/Desktop/website.jpg')
```

Here during bot loading the above three Forms could appear in any position i.e `Kyc` form could arrive at the end (third position) or second and similar for rest. So I want to know If I could check condition like if KYC form text  is presenet then i need to click the xpath right below it i.e `Label`  Any hint on this ?

Here is second file upload issue.

(+) button click  code

`WebDriverWait(self.driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Citizenship Certificates')]/../..//i[@class='fa fa-plus ' ]"))).click()`

second upload citizen ship code.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//span[contains(text(),'Citizenship Certificates ')]/../..//input[@type='file' and(@accept='.pdf')])[2]").send_keys('/home/navaraj/Desktop/{}'.format(row[75]))
```

Comment: Can you show, what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload files by Selenium the better approach is to send the file path directly to the input element, not by clicking elements.
Here you have 2 forms containing upload .pdf files inputs and single input for uploading .jpg files.
So, to upload the .pdf file in KYC form you can do this:  .
Let's say your file is located on the disk in "C://Downloads//kyc_pdf_file.pdf" you can do this:

```
kyc_pdf_file_path = "C://Downloads//kyc_pdf_file.pdf"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.//span[@class='document-type' and (contains(.,'KYC'))]]//input[@type='file' and(@accept='.pdf')]").send_keys(kyc_pdf_file_path)
```

Uploading file to Citizenship form:

```
citizenship_pdf_file_path = "C://Downloads//citizenship_pdf_file.pdf"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.//span[@class='document-type' and (contains(.,'Citizenship'))]]//input[@type='file' and(@accept='.pdf')]").send_keys(citizenship_pdf_file_path)
```

While uploading ".jpg" will be similarly:

```
jpg_file_path = "C://Downloads//jpg_file.jpg"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file' and(@accept='.jpg')]").send_keys(jpg_file_path)
```

**UPD**
The XPath for the Citizenship Certificates pdf upload is

```
//span[contains(text(),'Citizenship Certificates ')]/../..//input[@type='file' and(@accept='.pdf')]
```

And for the KYC Form is

```
//span[contains(text(),'KYC Form')]/../..//input[@type='file' and(@accept='.pdf')]
```

Here is second file upload issue.

(+) button click  code

`WebDriverWait(self.driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Citizenship Certificates')]/../..//i[@class='fa fa-plus ' ]"))).click()`

second upload citizen ship code.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//span[contains(text(),'Citizenship Certificates ')]/../..//input[@type='file' and(@accept='.pdf')])[2]").send_keys('/home/navaraj/Desktop/{}'.format(row[75]))
```

Comment: How will I identify It is xpath for KYC or it is for CitizenShip? as I mention the uploading buttons keeps changing

Comment: In my opinion we should check if the pdf is for KYC form or It is for CitizenShip Form only way to distinguish is to find text content.

Comment: In the XML you presented I see no KYC or Citizenship so I can't distinguish between what I don't see.

Comment: `<span _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" class="document-type">
            KYC Form <!----><span _ngcontent-kkx-c10="" style="margin-left:5px;color:red;">* </span>
        </span>` This is located here @Prophet

Comment: OK, I see. So, both KYC and Citizenship forms are having upload files inputs all the times, just the order of their appearance is changing?

Comment: Yeah Sometime Jpg file upload comes at top and some time KYC comes at top and even sometimes Citizen ship comes at top so I am unable to distinguish which pdf file i.e citizen or Kyc to be upoaded for pdf file.

Comment: See if updated answer is what you asked for

Comment: I came to realize that the xpath was not correct any solutin on this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Actually the xpath you answered in your answer is still not unique sir I also lately came to know about this. It provides 2 items for same xpath sir,

Comment: Did you provide me a link to the website so I could find the correct and unique locator?

Comment: the website link is `https://tms17.nepsetms.com.np/client-registration` please select client type = Individual on first page  and directly headover document upload i.e page 6. And please notice that the upload button keeps changing its position on every reload.

Comment: any Hint really stucked on the problem :(

Comment: Updated the answer. Now it should work. You know, it's difficult to give correct locator without seeing the actual web page :)

Comment: That worked like charm thank you so much for responding my comment

Comment: can you please let me know `/../..//` about this or any documentation?

Comment: `/..` is going one level up with xpath.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457563/xpath-get-element-above

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676169/how-to-traverse-back-to-the-parent-node-in-the-xml-file-by-using-xpathusing-xsl

Comment: I tried clicking second upload button i.e Citizenship Certificates using this xpath `(//span[contains(text(),'Citizenship Certificates ')]/../..//input[@type='file' and(@accept='.pdf')])[2]` this method but I dont know why in my code I am getting no element exception as the same xpath works fine in inspect in browser

Comment: indexing does not this way? sir i tried to get second button by index

Comment: There is no such element. `//span[contains(text(),'Citizenship Certificates ')]/../..//input[@type='file' and(@accept='.pdf')]` is an unique locator. There is no second element with such locator...

Comment: we can find that xpath only after  clicking (+) upload button in the link I provided and we will see that xpath.... does this mean xpath is not detected by this situation any solution to overcome this?

Comment: Well, you didn't mention clicking `+` button before... After clicking `+` there will be `(//span[contains(text(),'Citizenship Certificates ')]/../..//input[@type='file' and(@accept='.pdf')])[2]` element there. Even `(//span[contains(text(),'Citizenship Certificates ')]/../..//input[@type='file' and(@accept='.pdf')])[5]` if you click `+` at least 5 times. I just saw that. But these elements are not visible and you have to wait for these elemems appearance after clicking the `+` button some time...

Comment: I tried using Webdriver wait for around 10 sec I am always getting no element found exception in code while browser show unique xpath

Comment: That's strange. I can't see your code, but if you wrote it correctly it should work

Comment: sorry I edited your answer please ignore that edit I have added part of my code any suggestion regarding code?

Comment: It's mainly for your use, so I don't care :)

Comment: no i added second upload related code in my qsn any wrong in wait in code.?

Comment: I trust you. In case this code worked for you it should be correct

Comment: thank you  so much for your help hope i can solve this :(